# Error while loading Module Controllers from Test Fragment in Jmeter4.0 & 5.0

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-5.0

I've been trying to use a Main-Fragment Framework with JMeter but encountered an error while using Module controller within the fragment.jmx (see attached image), have you encountered this error? (tried on Jmeter 4.0 and 5.0)

Do you have any suggestions how to reuse pieces of code, because I have the same calls in five different places and every time I modify it I miss at least one place and it's very frustrating

[image: error loading module controller]

Thanks!

Comment: can you show the Include Controller node and the included test plan tree?

Comment: Hi, @UBIKLOADPACK , I updated the image with everything expanded and the error! I tried to enable/disable the "Test Fragment" in the fragment.jmx but have the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have selected any - **Module to Run** under **Modules -> Google Request**

This error might appear in case no module is selected under **Modules -> Google Request**

[image]

You can refer [How to use test fragments with Module and include controller](https://youtu.be/YwK-41LS5Lw?t=756)